# alien invasion of python code in the terminal - (why is it appending the letter D to the output?)

Tags: python, macos, terminal

So I'm working on a dorky little algorithm-- the point of which is very dull. All I want to know is why I'm the letter "D" is attached to the output on the terminal.

When the answer is 1, it gives me back 1D. When the answer is 2, it spits out 2D, etc. Why?

I don't think it has much to do with the code. The code is below if you think so. It might have to do with the way I'm ending the input stream, which is by pressing Ctrl + D (mac). It's not giving me 1^D, it's giving me 1D. Why?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *data = map(int, input.split())
    segments = list(map(lambda x: Segment(x[0], x[1]), zip(data[::2], data[1::2])))
    points = optimal_points(segments)
    print(int(len(points)))
    for p in points:
        print(p, end=' ')
```

It basically says, blah blah blah, get a list of numbers from the input stream / terminal, like this:

```
3
1 3
2 5
3 6
```

and do this to it:

```
def is_between(num_to_check, start, end):
    return num_to_check >= start and num_to_check <= end

def optimal_points(segments):
    end_first_segements = sorted(segments, key=attrgetter('end')) 

    count = 1
    i = 1
    current_end = end_first_segements[i -1 ].end
    next_seg = end_first_segements[i]
    end_points=[current_end]
    while i <len(end_first_segements):
        s = next_seg.start
        e = next_seg.end
        if(is_between(current_end, s, e)):
            try:
                i += 1
                next_seg = end_first_segements[i]
            except IndexError:
                break;
        else:
            try:

                count +=1 
                end_points.append(next_seg.end)
                next_seg = end_first_segements[i+1]
                current_end = next_seg.end


            except IndexError:
                break;
    return end_points
```

See, there's nothing in the code that says, "hey, you should attach the letter D to the output for no reason".

I keep seeing this in other little programs I've done as well. So I think it has to do with the terminal verse any code that I write. Thoughts?

The entire .py file:

```
# Uses python3
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter

Segment = namedtuple('Segment', 'start end')


def is_between(num_to_check, start, end):
    return num_to_check >= start and num_to_check <= end

def optimal_points(segments):
    end_first_segements = sorted(segments, key=attrgetter('end')) 

    count = 1
    i = 1
    current_end = end_first_segements[i -1 ].end
    next_seg = end_first_segements[i]
    end_points=[current_end]
    while i <len(end_first_segements):
        s = next_seg.start
        e = next_seg.end
        if(is_between(current_end, s, e)):
            try:
                i += 1
                next_seg = end_first_segements[i]
            except IndexError:
                break;
        else:
            try:

                count +=1 
                end_points.append(next_seg.end)
                next_seg = end_first_segements[i+1]
                current_end = next_seg.end


            except IndexError:
                break;
    return end_points


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *data = map(int, input.split())
    segments = list(map(lambda x: Segment(x[0], x[1]), zip(data[::2], data[1::2])))
    points = optimal_points(segments)
    print(int(len(points)))
    for p in points:
        print(p, end=' ')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get `^D\n1\n3` from your example input. You should try using another method of reading the input in. The `^D` is always going to display if you hit Ctrl + D.

Comment: I would suggest paring the program down to a minimal example that exhibits the behaviour you are experiencing to help people diagnose any issues.  Unfortunately I don't have access to a Mac and can't reproduce the issue. See a possible solution in my answer though...

Comment: @MorganThrapp "The The ^D is always going to display if you hit Ctrl + D." That's actually not accurate when you put hitting Ctrl + D in different contexts. This issue being one of those contexts

Comment: @Gavin thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly reproduce your exact issue, but I do see something strange where the last line of output ends with a % sign in linux.

So my minimal working example to reproduce this behaviour is simply:

```
print('1 2', end=' ')
```

If I add an empty print statement at the end of the program this removes the behaviour, ie by adding `print()` at the very end.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that your hack will also work on my mac.. given mac underpinnings. Thanks for the suggestion.